# Post body is not getting encoded even after adding filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the CharacterEncodingFilter in place(first filter) in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when I make a POST request, the body does not get encoded
Req Body Sent:

```
{
    "hi": "您好"
}
```

But received as

```
{
    "hi": "??"
}
```

Comment: Which web server are you using? Tomcat 7 by chance? If you upgrade to Tomcat 8, it should automatically serve UTF-8 by default. (unlike tomcat 7 which serves the OS charset by default, so ISO... under windows)

Comment: tomcat7 in prod but using jetty mvn plugin in dev. Also I use Ubuntu with default charset as UTF-8

Comment: Your received content does NOT look like it is a problem with the request encoding (I would expect more 4 to 6 characters, and more weird once when the response encoding is not taken in account and instead ISO 8859-1 is used) -- have you checked that his is not simply a problem with you font? - How do you have printed the posted "received" content?  - What is the encoding send by the client/browser in the HTTP-header?

Comment: I received ''??". I check the bytes, they were {63, 63} so indeed its a ?. Client is not doing any encoding.

Comment: Ones strange thing is happening that all non-ascii characters are received as ? (63)

Comment: have you checked the sended response content on the wire?

Comment: One more question about your setup: who send the request to whom? - Does a browser send this request to an spring-web-application?

Comment: Yes the browser is sending the request

Comment: @barunsthakur: is the content of the http request that is send by the browser still correct (6-8 bytes for the 2 unicode UTF-8 chars, or is it already broken (two byte ?? ascii)? -- you could check this with any browser plugin like Firebug or some already build in debugging tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `file.encoding` to `UTF8` in tomcat worked. I don't know why tomcat was not working when system encoding was `UTF-8`.

According to Java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

> The following tables show the encoding sets supported by Java SE 7. The canonical names used by the new java.nio APIs are in many cases not the same as those used in the java.io and java.lang APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The `CharacterEncodingFilter` does not change the encoding of the requests (or response) content, it set only the request/response http-header.

@See code of [CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/2.5.6/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.java#CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%2Cjavax.servlet.FilterChain%29)

Comment: Any way to do it in the app?

Comment: This depends on the cause of your problem. I have written some questions in a comment to your question.